# How to paste into Outlook from Microsoft Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, outlook

I want to write some VBA code that will automatically create a new email from an RTF document. I'm using the following programs:
1. Microsoft Word 2013
2. Microsoft Outlook 2013

I have managed to do everything I want except how to paste the content that I copied into the body of the email.

I have searched all over the web for how to do this however I have not found any simple way of doing this. In addition, all of the examples that I have found were related to Microsoft Excel. I have noticed that there is a difference when using Microsoft Word.

Below is the code that I have written:

```
Sub SendDocAsMail()

Dim oOutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim TheUser As String
Dim Subject As String
Dim ClientRef As String
Dim Body As String
Dim Signature As String
Dim SigString As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim Pos As Integer
Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments

TheUser = Environ("UserName")

On Error Resume Next

'Start Outlook if it isn't running
Set oOutlookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If Err <> 0 Then
    Set oOutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End If

'Create a new message
Set oItem = oOutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'Copy the open document to subject and body

'Change only Mysig.htm to the name of your signature
    SigString = Environ("appdata") & _
                "\Microsoft\Signatures\" & TheUser & ".htm"

Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
Subject = Selection.Text
Subject = Left(Subject, Len(Subject) - 1)
ClientRef = Subject
ClientRef = Right(ClientRef, Len(ClientRef) - 1)
For i = 1 To Len(ClientRef)
    If Mid(ClientRef, i, 1) = "|" Then
        Pos = i
    End If
Next i
ClientRef = Left(ClientRef, Pos - 1)

Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
Selection.TypeParagraph
Selection.TypeParagraph
Selection.InsertFile (SigString)

Selection.WholeStory
Selection.Copy

oItem.To = "xxxx@xxxx.co.il; xxxx@xxxx.co.il"
oItem.BCC = "xxxx@xxxx.co.uk"
oItem.Subject = Subject
'oItem.Body = 'NEED HELP
'Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)

oItem.Display

Set myAttachments = oItem.Attachments
'myAttachments.Add.PathName = "C:\Users\" & TheUser & "\Dropbox\PATENT\Bressler\" & ClientRef & "\"
'Clean up
'    Word.ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
'    Word.Application.Quit SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges


End Sub
```

All help in pasting the copy text with the original formatting would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a handle on the MailItem's Inspector which has a `.WordEditor` (basically MS Word Document instance)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868098.aspx

This should do the trick:

```
oItem.To = "xxxx@bxxxx.co.il; xxxx@xxxx.co.il"
oItem.BCC = "xxxx@docs.xxxx.co.uk"
oItem.Subject = Subject
'oItem.Body = 'NEED HELP

Dim mailWord as Object 'WordEditor
oItem.Display
Set mailWord = oItem.GetInspector.WordEditor
mailWord.Range(0).PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
```

**Explanation**

The explanation is fairly simple. In order to use a method like `PasteSpecial` you need to be working with an object that has that method available. The `MailItem` class does not directly have this, but it does contain the `Inspector.WordEditor` which is a word Document -- so any method you would use in word should be available to the `olItem.Inspector.WordEditor`.

**FOLLOW-UP:**

I would just use the `FileDialog` to select files to attach, like so:

```
Dim filePicker As FileDialog
Dim fileName As Variant

Set filePicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
filePicker.AllowMultiSelect = True

'### specify the folder default for the fileDialog object
filePicker.InitialFileName = "C:\Path\to\your\folder\" 
filePicker.Show

For Each fileName In filePicker.SelectedItems
    oItem.Attachments.Add (fileName)
Next
```

Alternatively, and this may be simpler or it may be more problematic as is sometimes the case when you hand the thread over to another application:

```
olItem.GetInspector.CommandBars.ExecuteMSO "AttachFile"
```

I would prefer the `FileDialog` method just because it gives you more control over the resulting selections.

Comment: Thank you so much for giving me such a quick response. I have been tackling this issue for three days now.
Can you possibly give me a quick explanation of why this works so that I can learn the reasoning behind the code.

Also, it seems to me that you would be the right person to ask the following question:
I would like the macro to open up the attachments dialogue to a specific folder. I couldn't find any method that fits the bill. What would be my best way of implementing the above?

Comment: See revisions to my answer above :)

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help!!!

Out of curiosity, why would the file dialog work as opposed to using something from the Attachments object? The first place I looked to find a method was in the Attachments object. In my going about coding the wrong way?

Comment: The `FileDialog` method uses the `olItem.Attachments` object and adds each -- this is explicitly *part of the VBA code*.  If you rely on the `.ExecuteMSO` method, that should also work. They should both work. My preference would just be for explicit solution, rather than handing the process over to something that is outside of the program's execution code.